# PHP error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de visualizar una fila de una base de datos (mysql) en una tabla html:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getIpequipo() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mantenedor\controller\equipoController.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mantenedor\welcome.php(70): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mantenedor\controller\equipoController.php on line 30

El código del `ControllerEquipo.php` es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
$equipos = new Equipos;
$datos = $equipos->mostrarDatos();
if($datos){ ?>
    <div class="table-section col-10" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        <div class="table-responsive" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <table class="table table-bordered w-auto small">
                <thead class="thead thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <!--                        <th scope="col">Id</th> -->
                        <th scope="col">IP Equipo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tipo Equipo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                        <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                        <th scope="col">Procesador</th>
                        <th scope="col">RAM</th>
                        <th scope="col">HDD</th>
                        <th scope="col">Monitor</th>
                        <th scope="col">Arquitectura</th>
                        <th scope="col">Versión SO</th>
                        <th scope="col">Versión Office</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    $d = $datos;
                    // Imprimir dato para comprobar funcionalidad
                    echo "Dato IP: "; print_r($d->getIpequipo());
                    // Imprime correctamente la IP seteada en la vista web
                    foreach ($datos as $d){  ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getIpequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getTipoequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getEstadoequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getMarcaequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getProcesadorequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getRamequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getHddequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getMonitorequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getArquitecturaequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getSoequipo();?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $d->getOfficeequipo();?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

El código perteneciente a la función mostrarDatos() incluído en la clase Equipo es el siguiente:

```
public function mostrarDatos(){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM equipos";
    try{
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $this->setIdequipo($fila['idEquipos']);
                $this->setIpequipo($fila['ipEquipos']);
                $this->setTipoequipo($fila['idTipoEquipos']);
                $this->setEstadoequipo($fila['idEstadoEquipos']);
                $this->setMarcaequipo($fila['marca_equipos']);
                $this->setProcesadorequipo($fila['procesador_equipos']);
                $this->setRamequipo($fila['ram_equipos']);
                $this->setHddequipo($fila['hdd_equipos']);
                $this->setMonitorequipo($fila['monitor_equipos']);
                $this->setArquitecturaequipo($fila['arquitectura_equipos']);
                $this->setSoequipo($fila['so_equipos']);
                $this->setOfficeequipo($fila['office_equipos']);
                $_SESSION['cont'] = $result->num_rows;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error EN CATCH" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el código de esta función getIpequipo()? No debería ser $equipos->getIpequipo()??

Comment: @Eric lo publiqué recientemente

Comment: Te faltó detallar ésta función getIpequipo()

Comment: Ya hay algo raro en tu forma de instanciar la clase: `$equipos = new Equipos;`... generalmente la llamada se hace así: `$equipos = new Equipos(parametros si los hay);`. Luego, el mensaje de error es claro: `$d` no es un objeto, sino una cadena. Debes revisar desde el principio la forma de usar las clases. Algo que te ayudará mucho será la depuración con `var_dump`, por ejemplo si haces algo como `var_dump($d);` podrás analizar lo que es `$d` realmente por dentro. Es extraño que desde el método `mostrarDatos()` devuelvas `$this` ¿por qué? ¿qué representa ese `$this` según tú?